# Edit File on Click of a button in Lazarus

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

Like I posted in a previous thread I want to create a little program which edits one line in a .ini file. Now I have implemented a button but don't further. I basically want to implement the following scenario:

1) Click Button

2) Because of button click, program opens .txt/.ini file (in background) the file is located in the same folder

3) One word in text file is changed with new word

4) file gets saved

5) message pops up

```
procedure TLauncher.ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);

    var

    begin

     ShowMessage('.Ini-File was edited')
    end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's simple to do, if you split what you want to do into procedures that only
do one thing each.

Assume your form has a string variable IniFileName which you initialize however
you want, e.g. using a TOpenDialog.  Then you can have

```
procedure TForm1.LoadIni;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.LoadfromFile(IniFileName);
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveIni;
begin
  Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(IniFileName);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click;
begin
   if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
     IniFileName := OpenDialog1.FileName;
     LoadIni;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click;
begin
   SaveIni;
   ShowMessage(IniFileName + ' saved to disk');
end;
```

Comment: Alright i tried it and got a few errors.
I assume that it's because i haven't initalized the TForms, where do i have to do this?

Comment: If your main form contains only the code in my answer, there won't be any errors - instead of trying with your existing project, just create a new one, it'll only take a couple of minutes.  Drop a couple of bttons, a TOpenDialog and a TMemo on it.  Use Button1 to invoke OpenDialog1.Execute and button Lazarus should automatically create an instance of TForm1 when you run the project.

Comment: See update to my answer, which should be all the code you need.

Comment: Yes, sorry I haven't looked in the comments for a long time but it worked. Thank you.